# What is Linux native debugging symbols format?

Tags: linux, debugging

[GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.4/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#Debugging-Options) says that the `-g` option *produces debugging information in the operating system's native format (stabs, COFF, XCOFF, or DWARF 2)*.

So, what is Linux native debugging symbols format? What is it called?

---

Update: I've just found a 15-year old [gcc mailing list discussion](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2000-10/msg00655.html) where it was said that the native format at that point was stabs and then they were considering to switch to DWARF2. But it was 15 years ago... Any updates? =)

Comment: According to the [DWARF page on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF), *"Linux followed suit, and DWARF-2 did not become the default until the late 1990s."*.  I'd like to see a more authoritative source though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Linux the default is now Dwarf 2 and/or 4. To see this, run `readelf --debug-dump=info` on a binary containing debug symbols (or stripped symbols); for example, on Fedora, with `glibc-debuginfo` installed, running `readelf --debug-dump=info /usr/lib/debug/bin/gencat.debug` will give you something like

```
 <1><ea>: Abbrev Number: 0
  Compilation Unit @ offset 0xeb:
   Length:        0x5c (32-bit)
   Version:       2
   Abbrev Offset: 0x52
   Pointer Size:  8
 <0><f6>: Abbrev Number: 1 (DW_TAG_compile_unit)
    <f7>   DW_AT_stmt_list   : 0x83
    <fb>   DW_AT_ranges      : 0x0
    <ff>   DW_AT_name        : ../sysdeps/x86_64/crti.S
    <118>   DW_AT_comp_dir    : /usr/src/debug////////glibc-2.21/csu
    <13d>   DW_AT_producer    : GNU AS 2.25
    <149>   DW_AT_language    : 32769   (MIPS assembler)
```

This is a set of Dwarf 2 information (see the `Version:` header for version information; the same binary includes Dwarf 2 and Dwarf 4 sections).

Comment: Can you please elaborate on *"the **same binary** includes Dwarf 2 **and** Dwarf 4 sections"*? Otherwise you seem to be right, Linux uses DWARF. Also the latest [documentation for gcc-5.2.0](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#index-gdwarf-_0040var_007bversion_007d-640) says that when you use `-gdwarf` option the default DWARF version is 4. Though the same section of documentation for gcc-4.7.4 (I have gcc-4.7.2 here) says that the default is DWARF version 2.

Comment: So it seems that on Linux with gcc-4.7.2: `gcc -g` == `gcc -gdwarf` == `gcc -gdwarf-2`

Comment: @golem On the Fedora system I have here, running the command I gave lists Dwarf sections with both versions 2 and 4 in the same binary, hence my comment. The binary was built with gcc 5.1.1; perhaps building with Dwarf 4 includes version 2 sections for backwards compatibility, but that's just a guess, I'd have to investigate further.

Comment: Since gcc 4.8, `gcc -g` uses Dwarf 4: https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/changes.html